# error in XML document (2, 2) on deserializing rdl file

Tags: c#, xml, reporting-services, report

I am trying to read an rdl file as c# objects using XmlSerializer class. This is what I am doing

```
Report myReport = null;
FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(path);
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Report),"http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting");
myReport = (Report)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
```

The last line gives the following error:
**An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll.
Additional information: There is an error in XML document (2, 2)**

I opened my report(rdl) using microsoft report builder and it opened successfully. I checked the xml and it looks fine. How do I resolve this ? I am using visual studio 2015, .net framework 4.5.2, sql server 2019

Comment: Show a few first lines this xml.

Comment: most probably xml is badly formatted

Comment: the code is failing on line 2 character 2.  When I've seen this error before the first line did not have UTF-8 (usually UTF-16).

Comment: It did have utf-8. and the formatting seems fine as well